# Java - string split error

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to split a string and return each sub-string to an array in Java (easier in c#) but the compiler is not having it. I keep getting an index out of bounds error when I try to call the value of any string in the array indexed higher than 0. Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int setter = 3000;
        String num = in.next();
        String[] numbers = num.split(" ");
        int j = numbers.length;
        for (int i =0; i < numbers.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(j);
```

Even the length of the array being returned is 1.

Comment: my first input is 5..then..."1 2 3 4 5"

Comment: Your `in.next()` just returns a single token.  You might want `in.nextLine()` instead.  Everything is "easier in C#" if you don't bother reading the Javadoc and call the wrong method.

Comment: Mr. Wallace, that fixed the error but now its only accepting one line of input and not two

Comment: Right, you might want to insert an extra call to `nextLine()` to read the newline character that occurs after your first input.

Comment: Ok adding an extra call fixed the problem and it seems to be working as it should, thanks Mr. Wallace.

Answer (score 0):

As David Wallace said in comments: you should use nextLine from Scanner...
But... why read line to split into int?

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = null;

    List<List<Integer>> all = new ArrayList<>();

    while ((line = in.nextLine()) != null) {
        final String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        List<Integer> forOneLine = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final String token : tokens) {
            try {
                final Integer value = Integer.valueOf(token);
                forOneLine.add(value);
            } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
                // Not an Integer
            }
        }
        all.add(forOneLine); 
    }
```

Is it ok now?

Comment: How its supposed to work is the user first enters how many numbers he wants to input...i.e 5... then he enters 5 numbers "1 2 3 4 5" and those numbers are split into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up parsing to an integer

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = in.nextLine();
        int ne = Integer.parseInt(n);
        String m = in.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = m.split(" ");
        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(m);
        for (String string : numbers) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```